Setup TLSv1.3 and removed TLSv1.0, TLSv1.1 and TLSv1.2 from nginx.conf file but TLS Checker still showing 1.0, 1.2 and 1.2 Enabled
Project Is built In Angular 17 and we have used Nginx Server and hosted on Azure.
We have setup Container Registry and Container Instance.
Here is the nginx.conf ssl_protocol setup.
ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;

ssl_ciphers ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-RC4-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-RC4-SHA:AES128:AES256:RC4-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK;

ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

So as per this above configuration TLS 1.3 should be Enabled and the rest should be Disabled.
But when I checked the website at TLS Checker (https://www.cdn77.com/tls-test/) It showed all are Enabled.
enter image description here
I've tried with multiple ways and it didn't reflected. Can you please guys quick help on this?
Only TLS 1.3 should be Enabled and rest should be disabled.

Please share nginx logs

Please do these steps, refresh and see if the issue persists. First ensure that the configuration changes were made in the correct nginx.conf file or the specific server block files that are actually in use by Nginx. Restart Nginx sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx. Ensure that no older configurations are cached i.e. Clear Cache. If you are using Azure services such as Azure Front Door or Azure Application Gateway, check their TLS settings as well. And most importantly check Nginx error logs

Here’s one example how your SSL configuration block in nginx.conf or the specific site’s server block (/etc/nginx/sites-available/yourconfig) should ideally look-

`server {
listen 443 ssl http2;
listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
server_name yourdomain.com;
ssl_certificate /path/to/ssl/certificate.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /path/to/ssl/private.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;  # Ensure only TLSv1.3 is enabled
ssl_ciphers 'TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384:TLS_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256:TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256';
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

# Additional SSL settings
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
ssl_session_timeout 10m;

# Your server configuration

}
`

References:

SSL errors are reported after upgrading to TLS 1.2
Configure TLS 1.3


@Arko
nginx -t shows https://imgur.com/YreRcDI
I've restarted the Nginx server as well. https://imgur.com/Lv4bjYe

@Yaseen
/var/log/nginx On this path we have two files. access.log and error.log. Both files are empty and when I try to open it shows that access.log is a device file only.
Screenshot: https://imgur.com/AtdA9Tl

@Yaseen Here Is the nginx.conf file: https://easyupload.io/19hb5v

Did you check www.SITENAME.com or SITENAME.com on the ssltest? Your config only applies to the www-included domain. I also always recommend the moz-ssl-config-helper - it's quite a good reference ;)

@boppy SITENAME.com shows Certificate name mismatch. And www.SITENAME.com Is showing correctly.

The issue has been resolved. It was a domain SSL Issue.
